# Logo on VideoView?

Tags: android

I have a videoview on my application.

I can put buttons on videoview but imageview I could'nt put it.

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<VideoView android:id="@+id/video_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</VideoView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:text="@string/login"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="109dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:text="@string/signup"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Activity:
[My Activity.txt](http://www.videomp3indir.net/activity.txt)

I wanna put logo on video. What can I do about it?

Comment: Use the frame layout and put the logo "ImageView" on top of the video view

Comment: I used. But didn't work also.

Comment: can you share the UI of what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: My activity: http://www.videomp3indir.net/activity.txt

Comment: I was asking about the UI, screen shot of how it should look.

Comment: This is my videoview: http://i.hizliresim.com/yEDnkM.png I wanna do like this: http://i.hizliresim.com/dPJqVQ.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this problem with android:background item.

```
<VideoView android:id="@+id/video_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/pngname">
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <VideoView
    android:id="@+id/yourVideoViewId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/yourImageViewId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

try this